# Android - Custom NavType for List<Enum<*>>

Tags: android, kotlin, generics, android-jetpack-navigation

I am trying to create a custom `NavType` for `Enum` with below code:

```
class EnumListType<T : Enum<T>> : NavType<List<T>>(true) {

    @Suppress("TYPE_MISMATCH_WARNING")
    override fun get(bundle: Bundle, key: String): List<T> {
        val found = bundle.getStringArrayList(key)
        return found?.map { enumValueOf(it) } ?: emptyList()
    }

    @Suppress("TYPE_MISMATCH_WARNING")
    override fun parseValue(value: String): List<T> {
        return value.substring(1, value.length - 1)
            .split(',')
            .map { enum -> java.lang.Enum.valueOf(T::class.java, enum) }
    }

    override fun put(bundle: Bundle, key: String, value: List<T>) {
        bundle.putStringArrayList(key, values.map { it.name } as ArrayList<String>)
    }
}
```

Both for `get` and `parseValue`, my code fails to compile with below error:

```
Cannot use 'T' as reified type parameter. Use a class instead.
```

Is it even possible to achieve a solution for this? If yes, what's wrong with the above code and how to fix it up?

Answer (score 0):

```
class CustomType<T : Parcelable> : NavType<T>(isNullableAllowed = false) {
    override fun get(bundle: Bundle, key: String): T? = bundle.getParcelable(key)

    override fun parseValue(value: String): T {
        val type: Type = object : TypeToken<Class<T>>() {}.type
        return Gson().fromJson(value, type)
    }

    override fun put(bundle: Bundle, key: String, value: T) {
        bundle.putParcelable(key, value)
    }
}
```